# Increment Maven project.version using build-helper-plugin in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

You can use the `maven-build-helper-plugin` to parse the version and then use the `maven-version-plugin` to set new versions (see this [blog](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2015/04/increment-versions-maven-build-helper-versions-plugin/)):

```
clean build-helper:parse-version versions:set -DnewVersion=${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.${parsedVersion.minorVersion}.${parsedVersion.nextIncrementalVersion} versions:commit
```

This works fine when the command is executed as "maven goal"-prebuild-step in a Maven-job.

Now I'm trying to convert all my Maven-job to pipeline-jobs.

```
withMaven(
  // Maven-Installation
  maven: "${MavenHelper.MAVEN3D3D9}") {

  String command = 'mvn build-helper:parse-version versions:set -DnewVersion=${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.${parsedVersion.minorVersion}.${parsedVersion.nextIncrementalVersion} versions:commit -f ' + komponente.getPomPath()

  sh(command)      
}
```

This always gives me a `bad substitution` error as the shell script tries to parse these variables. But in this context the variables are filled by the `maven-build-helper-plugin` during execution.

> DnewVersion=${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.${parsedVersion.minorVersion}.${parsedVersion.nextIncrementalVersion}: bad substitution

I already tried to escape them via `DnewVersion=\${parsedVersion.majorVersion}....` but still get the same error.

Any advice to get it working without incrementing it manually before passing it to the version-plugin.

Answer (score 3):

The following is working:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    tools {
        maven 'Maven 3.6.0'
    }
    stages {
        stage('Change Version') {
            steps {
                sh 'mvn build-helper:parse-version versions:set -DnewVersion=\\${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.\\${parsedVersion.minorVersion}.\\${parsedVersion.nextIncrementalVersion}'
                sh "mvn build-helper:parse-version versions:set -DnewVersion=\\\${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.\\\${parsedVersion.minorVersion}.\\\${parsedVersion.nextIncrementalVersion}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great, thank you for showing the correct escaping! I combined it with `help:evaluate` to get the complete new version into a variable: `nextDevelopmentVersion = sh returnStdout: true, script: "mvn -q -N -DmultiPropExpression=\\\${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.\\\${parsedVersion.minorVersion}.\\\${parsedVersion.nextIncrementalVersion}-SNAPSHOT build-helper:parse-version help:evaluate -DforceStdout -Dexpression=multiPropExpression'`. So I can use `${nextDevelopmentVersion}` not only for `versions:set` later on, but also e.g. in a commit message. Works like a charm.